# VsCode Debugging python code unable to access local sitepackages

Tags: python-3.x, vscode-debugger

i'm trying to debug my python code but unable to access 'sitepackages' methods
vscode version 1.35.1
python 3.6.8

i understand that i can use the    'justMyCode' flag in the    launch.json file. 
i've tried both the true/false settings.

```
{
      // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
     // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/? 
    linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [        

       {
           "name": "Python: Current File",
           "subProcess": true,
           "type": "python",
           "request": "launch",
           "program": "${file}",
           "justMyCode": false,
           "console": "integratedTerminal"
       }
   ]
```

}

When i set the value to True and try to step in to the method i get the 'Could not load source '': Source unavailable' message.
with the flag set to false: i get an exception in pkgutil.py key error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the joke is on me , the issue is because i had 'uncaught excpetions' & 'raised exceptions' check boxes set in the breakpointssection of the debug module set as 'ON' it seems like it's a workaround but it solve my problem